# Get the incoming phone number?

Tags: java, android

i am developing a app that gets the incoming calling number .

this is my code through which i am trying to do this .

```
package com.example.callchecker;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity ;
import android.content.Context;
import android.telephony.*;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Main_Activity extends Activity {
    String number;
    TextView tv1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);
        tv1=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        TelephonyManager telephonymanager =
            (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        //register phone state
        PhoneStateListener callstatelestener = new PhoneStateListener() {
            public void OnCallStateChanged(int state , String incomingNumber) {
                number = incomingNumber;
                tv1.setText(number);
                // If phone ringing
                if(state==TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Phone Is Riging",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        };

        telephonymanager.listen(callstatelestener,
                PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_layout, menu);
            return true;
    }
}
```

but this do not do any thing even when the call is make when i am in this app ...
weather i have to make it working in background all the time ?????
and if this is the right way to get the incoming number ???

Comment: You have to use BroadcastReceiver to listen to changes in call state.
Put your phone state listener code in broadcast receiver.

Comment: using the BroadcastReciever can application get the phone number weather the application is not running ???

Comment: Yes , once you register the receiver it will listen to any changes for a particular action regardless of your application is running or not.

Comment: kaushal trivedi  can u plz give me your email address ?? so i can get more help from u .
thanks

Comment: yeah sure , my email is kaushal.t1991@gmail.com , you can contact me anytime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will find all the answers you need to solve your problem in this extensive tutorial:
http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html